# Demonstrate how to delete a particular key or keys from an S3 bucket using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

This [boto3 function](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=objects%20delete#S3.Bucket.delete_objects) allows for deletion of a list of keys from an S3 bucket.  Please could you demonstrate an example of how to use it with:

1. a single key to be deleted.
2. a list of multiple keys to be deleted.

With thanks.

```
delete_objects(**kwargs)
This operation enables you to delete multiple objects from a bucket using a  single HTTP request. You may specify up to 1000 keys.

Request Syntax

response = bucket.delete_objects(
    Delete={
        'Objects': [
            {
                'Key': 'string',
                'VersionId': 'string'
            },
        ],
        'Quiet': True|False
    },
    MFA='string',
    RequestPayer='requester'
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete one object:

```
response = bucket.delete_objects(
    Delete={
        'Objects': [
            {
                'Key': 'myObjectKey'
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

Delete two objects:

```
response = bucket.delete_objects(
    Delete={
        'Objects': [
            {
                'Key': 'myFirstObjectKey'
            },
            {
                'Key': 'mySecondObjectKey'
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

I feel like the documentation (which you linked) makes this extremely obvious. I'm curious as to how you found the documentation confusing.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation, it was your hint that sorted the issue. Was tangled up in the terminology; key as in s3 bucket key but also key as in python dictionary key:value. ;-)

Comment: even after running above code, and receiving status code 200 i still can download that file from s3, so it did not worked

Comment: This is the most absurd and ridiculous API I've ever seen. What is wrong with this library?

Comment: @Granitosaurus Your comment is not productive. If you have a suggestion for improving Boto3 I suggest submitting it here https://github.com/boto/boto3

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

```
# Delete key(s)
forDeletion = [{'Key':'IMG_20160807_150118.jpg'}, {'Key':'IMG_20160807_150124.jpg'}]
response = bucket.delete_objects(Delete={'Objects': forDeletion})

for elem in response.get('Deleted'):
    print(elem['Key'])
```

Output:

```
IMG_20160807_150118.jpg
IMG_20160807_150124.jpg
```